# AWS S3 putobject with public read permissions - .Net SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions

I am using the .Net SDK for AWS.

I want to put a file into S3 and make its content readable by public, I see that I can use the "Grants" property in order to do this, however I cant find the value inputs in the online documentation for some of the fields.

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
BucketName = "some-bucket",
Key = fileName,
FilePath = filePath,
StorageClass = new S3StorageClass("REDUCED_REDUNDANCY"),
ContentType = "text/csv",
Grants = new List<S3Grant>() {
new S3Grant() {
Grantee = new S3Grantee()
{
CanonicalUser = "Everyone",
DisplayName = "Everyone"
},
Permission = new S3Permission("open/download")}}
};
```

In the above request:

1) The grantee "Everyone" is just my guess, what should be the valid value there?

2) For S3Permission what is the valid value equivalent to my guess of "open/download"?

I understand I have to make list permission open to public at the bucket level as well, I can do everything via the console, I just can't seem to find the valid API request parameters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

got my answer in AWS forum @ https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=671223

Re-posting it here for ease:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_S3CannedACL.htm

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = "some-bucket",
    Key = fileName,
    FilePath = filePath,
    StorageClass = new S3StorageClass("REDUCED_REDUNDANCY"),
    ContentType = "text/csv",
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};
```

This would upload the file, and set it with Public Read permissions.

In case you get "Access Denied" errors, make sure you have "PutObjectAcl" permission in your IAM policy.

Comment: don't see CannedACL in putObject Params, only see ACL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: To add to this: when using IAM policy's visual editor, `PutObjectAcl` is not part of the `Write` access level, but rather the **`Permissions management`** access level.

Comment: Thanks - still works as a solution. I achieved this in the Java S3 SDK with PutObjectRequest: `PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, objectKey, file);`, then doing `putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);`.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone still searching for an answer, adding the **ACL:'public-read'** property did the trick.

```
      s3.putObject({ 
              BucketName = "some-bucket",
              Key = fileName,
              FilePath = filePath,
              ACL:'public-read'
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally landed here while looking for solution using NodeJS SDK v2, if you are also looking for NodeJS solution, here it is:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Nodejs SDK v2:

```
 const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });
 const params = {
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: "image.png",
    ACL: "public-read",  // <--------------------
  };

  s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
     // ???
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved with allowing all permissions in bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```